Flutter open AI Text Model
which text model should I need to used send message to openai in flutter.
following are the model that is tried  by me but it always says insufficient even i tried with new openai account ..
   final request = CompleteText(prompt: chatMessage.message, model: 'gpt-4o-mini');
    constant.printMessage('chat gpt request $request');

  final response = await chatGPT!.onCompletion(request: request);
  constant.printMessage('chat gpt response $response');

